# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation pipeline through annotation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way to define the aggregation pipeline "raw" string (with placeholders) in Spring Data the same way you can do it with `@Query` annotation on an method inside of a `MongoRepository<X, Y>` interface?

If yes, can you please provide a simple example?

Comment: As per the official documents of [4.10 Aggregation Framework Support] [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mongo.aggregation] I don't think it is possible.

Comment: this is something we're working on. See [DATAMONGO-2153](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2153) for updates.